# Leaflet: second page is not printed

Tags: leaflet

I wrote a LaTeX file with class `leaflet`, it compiles fine, 
preview on okular also looks good but when i try printing, 
the first page is ok, whereas 
the second page does not come out. 
I also tried to separate the pages of the pdf or print side by side.
Converting to tiff, without success.
Conversion to `.ps` does not properly work.

**Update**: commenting out both `includegraphics` **solves** the problem. 
commenting out only one does not.

**Update**: replacing essentially `leaflet` by article 
and uncommenting all specially related with `leaflet` 
solves the problem also. 
What is strange is that there are examples with `leaflet` and pics 
in leaflet-manual which works.

So it seems to me as if graphics in conjunction with `leaflet` is the problem.

**Update**: trying to provide a minimal example, 
endowing graphicx with option draft or demo 
yields an option clash although all graphic like packages were removed. 
Replacing usepackage by RequirePackage 
which is placed before documentclass{leaflet} 
makes the clash vanishing. 
This gives some indication that the class leaflet uses the graphics package.

With demo option the file prints fie. 
Maybe this indicates that my pictures are in a sense wrong.

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\listfiles
\errorcontextlines=99

\documentclass[notumble,frontside]{leaflet}

\renewcommand*\foldmarkrule{.3mm}
\renewcommand*\foldmarklength{5mm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{helvet}
\makeatletter
\def\ptmTeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.075emX\@}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ptmLaTeX}{L\kern-.3em
    {\setbox0\hbox{T}%
     %\vb@xt@ % :-)
     \vbox to\ht0{\hbox{%
                        \csname S@\f@size\endcsname
                        \fontsize\sf@size\z@
                        \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
                        A}%
                  \vss}%
    }%
    \kern-.12em
    \ptmTeX}
\makeatother
\let\TeX=\ptmTeX
\let\LaTeX=\ptmLaTeX


\usepackage{shortvrb}
\MakeShortVerb{\|}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}%[dvipsnames,usenames]

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor}  % [dvipsnames,usenames] [    pdftex]  
%\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{The problem with c'' and its solution DR-mechanism}
\author{Doehnert\&Reissner}

\CutLine*{1}% Dotted line without scissors 1st side
%\CutLine*{2}% Dotted line without scissors
%\CutLine*{3}% Dotted line without scissors 2nd side, at mark 
\CutLine*{4}% Dotted line without scissors 2nd side
\CutLine*{6}% Dotted line without scissors 1st side 

%\AddToBackground{1}{%  Background of a small page
%  \put(115,530){\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{oboeWippe.jpg}}}


%\AddToBackground{6}{%  Background of a small page
%  \put(0,0){\textcolor{YellowOrange}{\rule{\paperwidth}    {\paperheight}}}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}% supresses 1st pagenumber 


You dream that on your French oboe the c'' sounds as pleasant as a' or b', 
is easy to intonate and fits well into the sequence of adjacent tones, 
without struggling with the reed and the embouchure and 
without changing to the thumbplate system? 
-- There is no such c'' to be found on your oboe?

If you think so, 
try playing b' and press the lever at the side 
to open the half tone hole for c''! 
Place the forefinger of you right hand above the key.

%\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.9\textwidth}
%\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=0.02]{oboeWippe.pdf}%.jpg
%\end{center}

Do you hear the difference?

%\newpage

You want to play this c'', without learning a new fingering, 
preserving your accustomed haptic sensation? 
Our DR-mechanism (Doehnert-Reissner-mechanism) allows you to do this. 
You can borrow and try out one of our modified instruments 
to convince yourself of its quality. 
If you like it, we can equip your instrument with the DR-mechanism, 
regardless of whether you are playing an automatic 
or semi-automatik instrument, an oboe, an oboe d'Amore or an English     horn.

\newpage

\section{How the DR-mechanism works}

Applying the usual fingering, 
the DR-mechanism opens and closes the toneholes as if the c'' 
were played pressing the rocker at the side:
If you play c'', only the toneholes for c and b$\flat$ open, 
without closing the g tonehole, 
because it is no longer under the right hand forefinger, 
but rotated to the side and opened and closed by an additional key. 
The DR-mechanism does not affect any tone but c''.

And that is what it looks like: 

\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{drAll.pdf}%.jpg

\section{Who we are }

\begin{itemize}
\item
Ernst Reissner (+49-174-39 18 17 3): 
Mathematician, member of the 
"Institut für Musikinstrumentenforschung 'Georg Kinsky' e.V. Leipzig", 
has invented the DR-mechanism, created the principal design 
and holds the patent.  
\item
Uwe Doehnert (+49-341-14 99 451): 
Owner of the Holzblas-Atelier Leipzig, 
master craftsman for woodwind instruments and 
Principal Master (President) of the Guild of Music Instrument Makers     Leipzig, 
has realized the first working DR-mechanism and has perfected it, 
ready for series production.  
\end{itemize}

... both passionate amateur oboists. 
You reach us, parallely, via \url{info@doehnert-reissner.de}. 


\newpage

\section{How to purchase the DR-mechanism}

You want to purchase a new instrument equipped with DR-mechanism? 
Presently, the following manufacturers offer such instruments: 
%
\begin{itemize}
\item
Bulgheroni, Como (\url{http://www.bulgheroni.it/}), 
\item
Josef, Tokyo (\url{http://www.josef-oboe.com})
% Marigaux, Paris (\url{http://www.marigaux.com/})
\end{itemize}
%
Ask for the Doehnert-Reissner-mechanism, 
either directly in Tokyo/Como or ask your local dealer. 


Complementarily, 
we offer you to equip your present instrument with the DR-mechanism. 
% Marigaux and Bulgheroni hold up the warranty after the modification. 
% We endeavour to obtain similar commitments from other manufacturers as well. 

The modification comprises the following steps: 
%
\begin{itemize}
\item
consultation, to find out and meet your individual requirements 
\item
drilling a new g-tonehole and sealing the original one 
\item
mounting the new mechanism with premium-quality keys  
\item
adjusting the mechanism  
\item
testing your instrument's intonation and 
ensureing perfect even response in all register. 
\end{itemize}

\newpage

\section{Insights}

Regardless of the instrument, an oboist adapts to whatever he finds. 
He acquaints himself with his instrument 
and more or less compensates any deficiency, 
adjusting the embochure, the fingering and the reed, without even     knowing.

A professional player, 
intimately familiar with his instrument can always play pleasantly. 
A new instrument, even a better one, feels strange at first; 
it takes a few minutes until playing it is more relaxed 
than with the original instrument.

This is true for any manufacturer: 
There are oboes with satisfying c'', independent of the oboist, 
and others, which do not sound as agreeable. 
For each oboe you find an oboist who can play it 
and another one who does not get along with it at all...


\section{Further Information and Contact}

\url{http://www.doehnert-reissner.de}

\url{info@doehnert-reissner.de}

\newpage


\section{Imprint}


Handwerksmeister Uwe Döhnert \\
Sebastian-Bach-Strasse 20\\
D-04109 Leipzig

Zuständige Kammer: \\
Handwerkskammer Leipzig, \\
Dresdner Straße 11/13, \\
D-04103 Leipzig

Umsatzsteuer-Identifikationsnummer:
DE 213986191

\loggingall
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Well and then I have two files in jpg and in pdf format. With neither variant my file is working. 
What happened and any suggestions?

Comment: Two possibilities: (1) there is something wrong with your code; (2) there is nothing wrong with your code. If (1), we can't help as we know nothing whatsoever about it. If (2), we can't help as it has nothing to do with TeX. Therefore, your question precludes an answer on this site due to its essential features. If the preview is OK, I'd guess (2). It's off-topic because it is a printer/print driver issue.

Comment: We can't help you without furher information. Please add a MWE.

Comment: Of course I cannot give you the jpg...

Comment: @user2609605 Instead of your image, use the example image of graphicx package, see here: [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I tried with option demo or draft: then the problem disappears. But I did not find an example picture in the graphicx package.

Comment: @user2609605 simply add `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` after loading `graphicx` package.